# GetCurrentTime() doesnot return correct time

Tags: c++, mfc

I am using below api in my code

```
COleDateTime  timeStamp = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();
```

And it is giving incorrect value

When system time was 12:36:08 this was returning 03:36:08.

I checked my system time setting and it is using US regional settings.

Had anyone experienced similar behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();` is in UTC, so you need to convert it to your localtime, see [this](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?298477-COleDateTime-and-conversion-from-UTC-to-local-time):

```
COleDateTime dt;  // yor UTC time
..........
TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION timeZoneInformation;
DWORD dwTZ = GetTimeZoneInformation(&timeZoneInformation);
if(dwTZ == TIME_ZONE_ID_STANDARD || dwTZ == TIME_ZONE_ID_DAYLIGHT)
{
    SYSTEMTIME timeUTC 
    dt.GetAsSystemTime(&timeUTC);
    SYSTEMTIME timeLocal;
    SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(&timeZoneInformation, &timeUTC, &timeLocal);
    dt = COleDateTime(&timeLocal);
}
else
{
    //error handling
}
```

Also you can check this using the following [program](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724950(v=vs.120).aspx):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    SYSTEMTIME st, lt;

    GetSystemTime(&st);
    GetLocalTime(&lt);

    printf("The system time is: %02d:%02d\n", st.wHour, st.wMinute);
    printf(" The local time is: %02d:%02d\n", lt.wHour, lt.wMinute);
}
```

Comment: My time zone is UTC-5. and I don't see the 5hrous time difference between system time and time returned by GetCurrentTime().

Comment: @Geek please check your localtime and systime using `GetSystemTime` and `GetLocalTime` as in my second example

Comment: You don't need to convert COleDateTime to local time. It already does this in functions like COleDateTime::GetHour()

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: GetCurrentTime is NOT returning current time, it's identical with GetTickCount, returning time in milliseconds since the windows has started (basically: uptime).

From Windows' Help File:

The GetCurrentTime is obsolete. This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit versions of Windows. Win32-based applications should use the GetTickCount function or look up the System Up Time counter in the performance data in the registry key HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA.

DWORD GetTickCount(VOID)

The GetTickCount function retrieves the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since Windows was started.

The elapsed time is stored as a DWORD value. Therefore, the time will wrap around to zero if Windows is run continuously for 49.7 days

WINNT 0x0600 and later should use GetTickCount64 instead

Comment: You are quoting the wrong documentation. The question is about the MFC [COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/coledatetime-class?view=msvc-160#getcurrenttime), which is not based on `GetTickCount`.

Comment: I guess you are correct. Let it as note to another one who got confused as I am.